# Dashboard, 24 hours stats, shows negative revenue amount

Tags: magento-1.9

As above, the Magento dashboard shows a negative value for the 24 hour period.  There has been a change to the system where shop orders (we have a bricks and mortar store) are done via orders that are at a 100% discount through Magento.  There is a shopping cart rule set up to offer 100% discount for any orders from a customer in a certain customer group (e.g. the Shop customer).

Could this be causing the issue, or is something else at work here?  Never seen this before in our store in a year of running.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that although there was a 100% discount, there was still tax being applied.  Although it wasn't charged to the customer, this was enough to register on Magento as a negative value, hence the dashboard shows a negative value.

The fix was to have no tax applied to the relevant customer group.